# iPhone vertical view controller animation

Tags: iphone, animation, view, controller

I want it to look like the current screen goes up while the new screen comes from bottom, is there a way to do this?

I am not looking for something like presentModelViewController.

Answer (score 2):

You can just do something like this:

```
 [UIView animateWithDuration:2.0
                     animations:^{ 
                         view2.frame=CGRectMake(view2.frame.origin.x, 480, view2.frame.size.width, view2.frame.size.height);
                         view1.transform=CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0, -480);
                         view2.transform=CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0, -480);
                     }];
```

Comment: How to do that view view controller?
With view I don't get the buttons in another view

Comment: When I load the second view, I only get the view, not the buttons that are on it, just a blank view